# Using a string which contains quotes as parameter to a command in bash without additional escaping

Tags: bash, variables, quoting

#### Background

What I'm trying to do is exclude all submodules of a git repository in a find command. I know that I can exclude a single directory like this:

```
find . -not -path './$submodule/*'
```

So I built a command that generates a lot of these statements and stores them:

```
EXCLUDES=$(for submodule in $(git submodule status | awk '{print $2}'); do
    echo -n "-not -path './$submodule/*' ";
done)
```

#### Problem

But when I run `find . $EXCLUDES`, this does not work. I suspect this is because of a bash quoting strategy that I do not understand. For example, lets assume (`#` marks output):

```
tree .
# .
# ├── bar
# │   └── baz.scala
# └── foo.scala

set -x
EXCLUDES="-not -path './bar/*'"
find . -type f $EXCLUDES
# + find . -not -path ''\''./bar/*'\''' <---- weird stuff
# foo.scala
# baz.scala

find . -type f -not -path './bar/*'
# + find . -type f -not -path './bar/*'
# foo.scala
```

How do I tell bash not to to the weird quoting stuff its doing (see marked line above)?

Edit: @eddiem suggested using `git ls-files`, which I will do in this concrete case. But I'm still interested in how I'd do this in the general case where I have a variable with quotes and would like to use it as arguments to a command.

Comment: Are you just trying to `grep` for something in source files that are in your primary repo, but not in submodules?  If so, you can accomplish that with `git grep`.

Comment: you're protecting your `submodule` env. variable in simple quotes. So it's not evaluated. Use no quotes or double quotes.

Comment: @eddiem Nope, not grepping. It's to be part of a linting build step. For which I need a certain set of files.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't understand. Why would it be evaluated (do you mean globbing?) ? Changing everything to double quotes does not make a difference in the example below.

Comment: @fresskoma Do you only care about files that are in the repo (as opposed to unstaged new files, for example)?  If so, you can just use `git ls-files`.

Comment: @eddiem That is a good idea, thanks! Nonetheless I'd still be interested in why this doesn't work, since it seems like this would be useful in other situations too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weird stuff" you note is because bash only expands `$EXCLUDES` once, by substituting in the value you stored in `EXCLUDES`.  It does not recursively process the contents of `EXCLUDES` to remove single-quotes like it does when you specify the quoted string on the command line.  Instead, bash escapes special characters in `$EXCLUDES`, assuming that you want them there:

```
-not -path './bar/*'
```

becomes

```
-not -path ''\''./bar/*'\'''
             ^^         ^^ escaped single quotes
           ^^             ^^ random empty strings I'm actually not sure about
               ^       ^ single quotes around the rest of your text.
```

So, as @Jean-FrançoisFabre said, if you leave off the single quotes in `EXCLUDES=...`, you won't get the weird stuff.

So why isn't the first `find` working as expected?  Because bash expands `$EXCLUDES` into a single word, i.e., a single element of `argv` that gets passed to `find`.<sup>*</sup>  However, `find` expects its arguments to be separate words.  As a result, `find` does not do what you expect.

The most reliable way I know of to do this sort of thing is to use an array:

```
declare -a EXCLUDES    #make a new array
EXCLUDES+=("-not" "-path" './bar/*')
    # single-quotes       ^       ^ so we don't glob when creating the array
```

and you can repeat the += line any number of times for exclusions that you want.  Then, to use these:

```
find . -type f "${EXCLUDES[@]}"
```

The `"${name[@]}"` form, *with* all that punctuation, expands each element of the array to a separate word, but does not further expand those words.  So `./bar/*` will stay as that and not be globbed.  (If you do want globbing, `find . -type f ${EXCLUDES[@]}` (without the `""`) will expand each element of the array.)

**Edit** By the way, to see what's in your array, do `set|grep EXCLUDES`.  You will each each element listed separately.  You can also do `echo "${EXCLUDES[@]}"`, but I find that less useful for debugging since it doesn't show the indices.

<sup>*</sup> see the "expansion" section of [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).  "Parameter expansion," expanding things that start with `$`, cannot change the number of words on the command line — except for `"$@"` and `"${name[@]}"`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: @fresskoma Glad to help!  By the way, SMB SARSA FTW \o/ :)